# Jmeter - how to reset counter under a for each controller?

Tags: jmeter

I have my jmeter test as below - 
I have a for each controller, under which there is a JDBC request & an beanshell assertion under it.

My beanshell asserstion code is like this -

```
String value1 = "${__V(statusapi_${__counter(,)})}"; 
String value2 = vars.get("status_db_1"); 
String value9 = vars.get("tenant"); 
print(value1); 
if(value1 != null) {
    if(!value1.equals(value2)) {
                   Failure = true;
                              FailureMessage = value9 + ":  status name doesnt match, api: "+ value1 + "   db: "+ value2;
                              print(FailureMessage);
               } }  else {
    if(value2 != null) {
                   Failure = true;
                              FailureMessage = value9 + ":  status name doesnt match, api: "+ value1 + "   db: "+ value2;
                              print(FailureMessage);
               } }
```

I am using counter function for value1. I want to know how can I reset this counter to start with 1 for a new for each request ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need the `statusapi_`

My expectation is that you're using the wrong test element, __counter() function is incremented each time it's being called. So I believe you should switch to [Counter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) test element and configure it according to your scenario.

The Counter test element produces "normal" JMeter Variable which you can reset using i.e. `vars.put("your_counter_reference_name", "1");` in [Beanshell PreProcesssor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor).

---

Also be aware that [starting from JMeter version 3.1 it is recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting so consider migration to [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) as soon as possible. More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) for more details.

Comment: Thanks@Dmitri, I have added Counter test element to my plan, but I am not too sure on where to put the beanshell preprocessor ? I now have a ForEach>>Counter>>JDBC Request>>>Beanshell Asserstion

Comment: As a child of the JDBC Request I believe, check out [JMeter Scoping Rules - The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide) for more information

Comment: Thanks @Dimitri. But now I have run into another problem where the 'maximum' in my counter is not re-initializing with every loop(I am using a variable in there). I have started another thread with the question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48938403/how-to-reinitilize-maximum-in-counter-in-jmeter